# Можно ли формулой получить форматированный текст?

Tags: excel, open-office

Хочу выделить кусок текста ячейки в OpenOffice.org Calc. Но этот текст вычисляется.

Если я ввожу текст в ячейку руками, то могу форматировать любые его фрагменты: например, выделить первую строку жирным оранжевым. А как добиться того же эффекта, если строка собирается формулой из других ячеек? Даже при простом `=A3` форматирование теряется.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, формулы не могут менять формат ячейки. Но можно макросом.

В *VBA* (*MS Excel*) за форматирование символа (блока символов, всего текста) отвечает оператор *Characters*.

Пример кода. В диапазоне *A2:A10* форматируем часть текста:

```vb
Sub CharactersText()
Dim s As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = 2 To 10 ' перебираем 9 ячеек
        With Cells(i, 1)
            s = .Value ' текст изменяемой ячейки

            With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=7).Font ' формат первых 7 символов
                .Name = "Arial" ' шрифт
                .Size = 12 ' размер
                .Color = RGB(170, 110, 100) ' цвет
                .Bold = True ' жирный
                .Italic = True ' курсив
                .Underline = True ' черта
            End With
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: А как макросом?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Похоже на макрос для MS Excel. В OOo не работает: "Ошибка времени выполнения BASIC.
Подпрограмма или функция не определена." на строке `s = .Value`.

Comment: Да, это VBA. Указана метка Excel, В заголовке нет ударения на ОО... В вопрос могут заходить в поисках решения для MS Excel. К сожалению, для OO Calc не напишу.